# How to display an alert from server script in Siebel?

Tags: siebel

We have a Siebel 7.8 application, and a requirement to show a message when the user saves a record meeting certain conditions. Something like this:

```js
function BusComp_WriteRecord () {
  if (conditions) {
    TheApplication().RaiseErrorText("Terribly important message");
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't use `RaiseErrorText` because it prevents further events execution. That leaves me with either `alert` or `SWEAlert` (unless there is another option which I don't know of).

Both of them are supported only in browser scripts, and there is no browser version of the `BusComp_WriteRecord` event. All this means that I have to keep my validations in the server script event, and somehow invoke a browser script function which shows the message. The only way I've come up with is something like this:

*Server script (in the business component):*

```js
function BusComp_WriteRecord () {
  if (conditions) {
    TheApplication().SetProfileAttr("MyMessage", "Terribly important message");
  }
}
```

*Browser script (in an applet which is always loaded before the BC):*

```js
function Applet_Load () {
  listenerAlert();
}

function listenerAlert () {
  var message = TheApplication().GetProfileAttr("MyMessage");
  if ((message != null) && (message != "")) {
    TheApplication().SetProfileAttr("MyMessage", "");
    alert(message);
  }
  // Keep checking for messages each 0,5 seconds, forever...
  setTimeout("listenerAlert()", 500);
}
```

It does work, but it has an excessive impact on the servers performance. We have around 60 users per server, and apparently, checking a profile attribute twice a second for each user is too much (the CPU usage rises to 100%).

So, is there any other way to show an alert to the user in Siebel 7.8? It has to be an alert or similar, i.e. Siebel broadcasting messages are not an option.

Or, alternatively, if I have to stick with alert/SWEAlert: is there any other way to communicate between the server script and the browser script, without the endless polling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still can use browser scripts, you can write the code at applet level. The applet has

function Applet_PreInvokeMethod (name, inputPropSet)

You can check for name=="WriteRecord" ,do your validations there, and pop the Alert() prompt.

Do let us know if it worked.

Comment: That could work, but I would have to replicate the same code on every applet based on this BC, and there are *a lot* of them...

Comment: Hmm..well your existing solution also user applet browser script, but more lines. You could try this solution with fewer lines. Another thing I noticed, your existing script is in BusComp_WriteRecord , which fires AFTER the record is commited to db. So using RaiseErrorText here should not rollback any changes. The message will come up after record is saved.

Comment: Yes, but my browser script is writen only in one applet, because once the "listener" has been set up, it's available everywhere. With your solution (which is better than mine, at least yours works...), I'd have to replicate the same code over 10-15 applets.

Comment: And you're right, WriteRecord is fired after the commit, but we already have a lot of code in there (mostly web service integrations with external systems), with their own RaiseErrorTexts... no matter where I place my code, it would disrupt or be disrupted by something.

Answer (score 1):

If your application has a CTI client, this is your best option. This is how the application I work with handles server script alerts. The documentation is surprisingly good for this one, so I won't go into detail here. If you do have any questions, just comment, I am pretty well versed with our CTI alert functionality.

Basically you can add a command (@InvokeSWECommand) that you can execute from server script that in turn will execute a custom browser script method.

Only downside I can think of is this command is fire and forget (server script will keep executing). So, no waiting in browser script to get a value back from confirm() or anything.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/SiebCTIAdm/SiebCTIAdm_AdvConfig29.html

Answer (score 0):

there is another solution is create a new BS, on that BS(*BS Display Alert*) write a browser script to give alert (make sure this BS reads the message from Input arguments to reuse the same).
trigger/call this BS(*BS Display Alert*) with your Message as input Argument (`Inputs.SetProperty("BrowserMsg","Terribly important message")`)from the server script where you want to display alert...

when this BS called, it will display a message with "OK" button. on click OK button all your sub sequent events will resume...

Answer (score 0):

Use below for displaying alerts from server side in siebel

BS Name: LS Pharma Signature UI Service

MethodName: ShowConfirmDialog